# MVC 2 UpdateModel on Interface, Should ModelBinderAttribute be ignored?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have forms posting data from instances of a particular abstract class:

```
public abstract class IRestriction
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public abstract IModelBinder GetBinder();
}
```

The concrete type and PartialView are determined at runtime:

```
IRestriction restriction = (IRestriction)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(restriction.restriction_class));
```

The appropriate partial view is then rendered correctly.

When the form is sent back the type is inferred correctly and activated the same way.

However, I haven't been able to get UpdateModel to bind to the concrete implementation.

How do I get the Model to bind to the concrete type instead of the interface?

Things I've tried:

I've set the ModelBinderAttribute on the concrete class but it is being ignored.

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))]
public class ConcreteRestriction : IRestriction
```

I've cleared all the ModelBinders and added only the binder from the interface.

```
Binders.Clear();
Binders.Add(item.GetType(), item.GetBinder());
```

None of these is working.

Whats the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Is ModelBinderAttribute being ignored in error?

** ----------------------UPDATE----------------------**

Here is a solution for anyone else struggling with the same issue who happens to run across this.

The following class inherits Controller. Inherit it and call UpdateModelDynamic()/TryUpdateModelDynamic()

```
public class DynamicTypeController : Controller
{
    internal static bool IsPropertyAllowed(string propertyName, string[] includeProperties, string[] excludeProperties)
    {
        // We allow a property to be bound if its both in the include list AND not in the exclude list.
        // An empty include list implies all properties are allowed.
        // An empty exclude list implies no properties are disallowed.
        bool includeProperty = (includeProperties == null) || (includeProperties.Length == 0) || includeProperties.Contains(propertyName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        bool excludeProperty = (excludeProperties != null) && excludeProperties.Contains(propertyName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        return includeProperty && !excludeProperty;
    }

    protected internal bool TryUpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model) where TModel : class
    {
        return TryUpdateModelDynamic(model, null, null, null, ValueProvider);
    }

    protected internal bool TryUpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix) where TModel : class
    {
        return TryUpdateModelDynamic(model, prefix, null, null, ValueProvider);
    }

    protected internal bool TryUpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string[] includeProperties) where TModel : class
    {
        return TryUpdateModelDynamic(model, null, includeProperties, null, ValueProvider);
    }

    protected internal bool TryUpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties) where TModel : class
    {
        return TryUpdateModelDynamic(model, prefix, includeProperties, null, ValueProvider);
    }

    protected internal bool TryUpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties, string[] excludeProperties) where TModel : class
    {
        return TryUpdateModelDynamic(model, prefix, includeProperties, excludeProperties, ValueProvider);
    }

    protected internal bool TryUpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, IValueProvider valueProvider) where TModel : class
    {
        return TryUpdateModelDynamic(model, null, null, null, valueProvider);
    }

    protected internal bool TryUpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, IValueProvider valueProvider) where TModel : class
    {
        return TryUpdateModelDynamic(model, prefix, null, null, valueProvider);
    }

    protected internal bool TryUpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string[] includeProperties, IValueProvider valueProvider) where TModel : class
    {
        return TryUpdateModelDynamic(model, null, includeProperties, null, valueProvider);
    }

    protected internal bool TryUpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties, IValueProvider valueProvider) where TModel : class
    {
        return TryUpdateModelDynamic(model, prefix, includeProperties, null, valueProvider);
    }

    protected internal bool TryUpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties, string[] excludeProperties, IValueProvider valueProvider) where TModel : class
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
        }
        if (valueProvider == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("valueProvider");
        }

        Predicate<string> propertyFilter = propertyName => IsPropertyAllowed(propertyName, includeProperties, excludeProperties);
        IModelBinder binder = Binders.GetBinder(model.GetType());

        ModelBindingContext bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext()
        {
            ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, model.GetType()),
            ModelName = prefix,
            ModelState = ModelState,
            PropertyFilter = propertyFilter,
            ValueProvider = valueProvider
        };
        binder.BindModel(ControllerContext, bindingContext);
        return ModelState.IsValid;
    }


    protected internal void UpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model) where TModel : class
    {
        UpdateModelDynamic(model, null, null, null, ValueProvider);
    }

    protected internal void UpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix) where TModel : class
    {
        UpdateModelDynamic(model, prefix, null, null, ValueProvider);
    }

    protected internal void UpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string[] includeProperties) where TModel : class
    {
        UpdateModelDynamic(model, null, includeProperties, null, ValueProvider);
    }

    protected internal void UpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties) where TModel : class
    {
        UpdateModelDynamic(model, prefix, includeProperties, null, ValueProvider);
    }

    protected internal void UpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties, string[] excludeProperties) where TModel : class
    {
        UpdateModelDynamic(model, prefix, includeProperties, excludeProperties, ValueProvider);
    }

    protected internal void UpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, IValueProvider valueProvider) where TModel : class
    {
        UpdateModelDynamic(model, null, null, null, valueProvider);
    }

    protected internal void UpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, IValueProvider valueProvider) where TModel : class
    {
        UpdateModelDynamic(model, prefix, null, null, valueProvider);
    }

    protected internal void UpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string[] includeProperties, IValueProvider valueProvider) where TModel : class
    {
        UpdateModelDynamic(model, null, includeProperties, null, valueProvider);
    }

    protected internal void UpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties, IValueProvider valueProvider) where TModel : class
    {
        UpdateModelDynamic(model, prefix, includeProperties, null, valueProvider);
    }

    protected internal void UpdateModelDynamic<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties, string[] excludeProperties, IValueProvider valueProvider) where TModel : class
    {
        bool success = TryUpdateModelDynamic(model, prefix, includeProperties, excludeProperties, valueProvider);
        if (!success)
        {
            string message = String.Format("The model of type '{0}' could not be updated.", model.GetType().FullName);
            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I think it's a bug, but the ASP.NET MVC team disagrees](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/483001/in-asp-net-mvc-generic-try-updatemodel-methods-ignore-subtype-properties). Model binding looks at the static, compile-time type of the model. I don't like it, but that's how it is.

Comment: geez... you'd think they'd at least put in the option of providing your own type!

Comment: I'm looking in the source right now and you are correct.

Not sure what the reasoning is since it appears all the ValidateModel logic uses .GetType() instead of typeof().

Now I'm overriding it all just so I can switch that statement.

Thanks!

Comment: I updated the text with how I got around this. Hopefully it helps someone else.